# 'error: no matching function for call to ‘bpp::Parameter::setConstraint' in BioPP/bpp-phyl

Tags: c++, c, git, c++11, cmake

I have been trying to install  BioPP/bpp-phyl obtained with

```
git clone https://github.com/BioPP/bpp-phyl.git
```

I used cmake for compiling:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=[where to install, for instance /usr/local or $HOME/.local]
```

And then I tried to use `make`. It shows me the following error:

```
/home/ceglab2/Downloads/dignn/bpp-phyl/src/Bpp/Phyl/App/PhylogeneticsApplicationTools.cpp: In static member function ‘static bpp::TreeLikelihood* bpp::PhylogeneticsApplicationTools::optimizeParameters(bpp::TreeLikelihood*, const bpp::ParameterList&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, const string&, bool, bool, int)’:
/home/ceglab2/Downloads/dignn/bpp-phyl/src/Bpp/Phyl/App/PhylogeneticsApplicationTools.cpp:922:62: **error: no matching function for call to ‘bpp::Parameter::setConstraint(bpp::Constraint*, bool)’
           par.setConstraint(ic & (*par.getConstraint()), true);**

/usr/local/include/Bpp/Numeric/Parameter.h:269:18: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/ceglab2/Downloads/dignn/bpp-phyl/src/Bpp/Phyl/App/PhylogeneticsApplicationTools.cpp:927:45: **error: no matching function for call to ‘bpp::Parameter::setConstraint(bpp::IntervalConstraint*, bool)’
           par.setConstraint(ic.clone(), true)**;

/usr/local/include/Bpp/Numeric/Parameter.h:269:18: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/ceglab2/Downloads/dignn/bpp-phyl/src/Bpp/Phyl/App/PhylogeneticsApplicationTools.cpp: In static member function ‘static void bpp::PhylogeneticsApplicationTools::checkEstimatedParameters(const bpp::ParameterList&)’:
/home/ceglab2/Downloads/dignn/bpp-phyl/src/Bpp/Phyl/App/PhylogeneticsApplicationTools.cpp:1388:56: **error: cannot convert ‘const std::shared_ptr<bpp::Constraint>’ to ‘const bpp::Constraint*’ in initialization**
     const Constraint* constraint = pl[i].getConstraint();

make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bpp-phyl-shared.dir/Bpp/Phyl/App/PhylogeneticsApplicationTools.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1111: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/bpp-phyl-shared.dir/all' failed

make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bpp-phyl-shared.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't know the cause of the error.

---

I have installed bpp-core:

```
git clone https://github.com/BioPP/bpp-core.git
```

also I have installed bpp-seq:

```
git clone https://github.com/BioPP/bpp-seq.git
```

but unable to install `bpp-seq`.

I am using CMake version 3.10.2.

Comment: We cant know the cause either, as you did not include the actual error message of the compiler in your question. What you have quoted in bold and the first line after that is only cmake telling you that **something** went wrong when compiling *PhylogeneticsApplicationTools.cpp*. The actual error message is either somewhere before the output that you copied here, or it's in a text file in your build directory.

Comment: thank you for prompt response I have re-edited the question I hope this will help you to understand the problem.

Comment: Looks like a versioning problem. Maybe bbq-seq (last commit 2018) isnt compatible with the most recent bio++ base (2020). You could try to checkout an older version of bio++ and see if this helps. If that doesnt work, then your next best bet is to ask one of the bio++ developers for help.

Comment: thank you for your response i will defiantly try this.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion it helped problem is solved thank you.

Comment: @somilsharma If you found a solution to your problem, please consider writing up a brief Answer post explaining how you fixed it, to benefit future visitors to your Question.

Comment: Sorry i didn't post the solution, so here is the solution, just use an older version  of bpp-seq to compile against older version bpp-core for example compile bpp-seq version 2.4.0 against bpp-core version 2.4.0. I hope this helps.